# How to take the bus: 'from' or 'at'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

1) Which answer is more natural:

A: How can I get to the airport?

B: Take the airport bus **at** the bus station.

or

B: Take the airport bus **from** the bus station.

Or they are equal?

2) And what is the meaning of the verb 'to take' here:

**Take** the airport bus at the bus station.?

I think 'to take' doesn't mean 'to travel by using a particular form of transport'. 
  It's like  the synonym of 'to get' or 'to take a particular route, road'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two statements are equivalent.

Technically speaking, the *at* version is talking about the station as "the place where you get on the bus", while the *from* version is talking about the station as "the place where the bus begins its journey to the airport".  But since they are both the same place, there's really no distinction.

**Take** does mean exactly *Travel by using a particular form of transport* here; "Take the bus" specifies that the particular form of transport to be used is a bus.

Answer (score 1):

Both "take the bus from a particular place" and "take the bus at a particular place" are correct. Though the first one is more common, and the second one is mostly used to tell the time, instead of place - "take the bus at 1 o'clock" for example.

"to take the bus" here means "to catch the bus"